# Load database entries using a SELECT ... INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

For the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO main_app_provider (provider) 
VALUES ((SELECT distinct(provider) FROM raw_financials));
```

I get a `"subquery returns more than one row"`.

It seems the above is trying to do an INSERT into a single row. How would I load this into a table for multiple rows (i.e., so each `provider` is inserted into a new row)?

Comment: it IS trying to do an insert into a single row..

Comment: For reference, the MySQL manual shows the proper syntax for [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) and all other statements MySQL supports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `VALUES` keyword. The parentheses around the `SELECT` are not strictly needed either.

```
INSERT INTO main_app_provider (provider) SELECT distinct provider FROM raw_financials;
```

See the [MySQL `INSERT` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

Right syntax is without `values`:

```
INSERT INTO main_app_provider (provider) 
  SELECT distinct(provider) 
  FROM raw_financials
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

INSERT INTO main_app_provider (provider) 
SELECT distinct(provider) as Provider FROM raw_financials;